# lombok.configuration apply @Generated annotation in multi-module project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, lombok, jacoco

We have a multi-module gradle project which runs sonarqube analysis. Our models annotated with lombok constructors/getters/setters/etc. bring our code coverage score down. I tried to add a lombok.config file with the following property:

lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true

This was first added to the parent project, then moved to each child, then to each child's /src directory. However, the code coverage remains the same, and sonarqube still highlights the lombok Data/Getter/Setter/NoArgsConstructor/AllArgsConstructor/etc. annotations.

Furthermore, when inspecting the compiled classes, the Getter/Setter/equals/etc methods do not include the intended "Generated" annotation.

Our Parent project build.gradle file calls the plugins as:

```
plugins {
    id "jacoco"
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.7"
}
...
    jacocoTestReport {
        reports {
            xml.enabled true
        }
    }
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.login',  <pwd>
        property 'sonar.host.url',  <host>
        property 'sonar.projectKey',  <key>
        property 'sonar.java.coveragePlugin',  'jacoco'
        property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPath',  'build/jacoco/test.exec'
        property 'sonar.test.exclusions',  '**/src/test/java/**/*'
        property 'sonar.projectName',  <name>
    }
}
```

and lombok as:

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
```

The child modules generally have lombok dependencies of:

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:edge-SNAPSHOT'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:edge-SNAPSHOT'
```

Furthermore, running gradle dependencies in a given module shows:

```
annotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for source set 'main'.
\--- org.projectlombok:lombok -> 1.18.12
```

Is there something that we are missing?

Comment: you can exclude models from sonar coverage.

Comment: @Pirate, That might be what we have to do. I was looking to see if this would work first, but from what I have seen so far, it might not be possible.

Comment: you can try by setting and getting all properties in junits.

Answer (score 1):

> when inspecting the compiled classes, the Getter/Setter/equals/etc methods do not include the intended "Generated" annotation

in absence of [Minimal Reproducible **Complete** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) let me provide one:

given

`lombok.config`

```
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

`settings.gradle`

```
rootProject.name = 'basic-multiproject'
include 'module'
```

`module/src/main/java/Example.java`

```
@lombok.Data
@lombok.NoArgsConstructor
public class Example {

  private String msg;

  public static void uncovered() {
  }

}
```

`module/src/test/java/ExampleTest.java`

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class ExampleTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        new Example();
    }
}
```

and `module/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "jacoco"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

jacoco.toolVersion = "0.8.7"
```

using Gradle 6.8.3

execution of

```
gradle build jacocoTestReport
```

produces `module/build/classes/java/main/Example.class`
that according to command

```
javap -v -p module/build/classes/java/main/Example.class
```

contains `lombok.Generated` annotations:

```
  public java.lang.String getMsg();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: getfield      #1                  // Field msg:Ljava/lang/String;
         4: areturn
      LineNumberTable:
        line 5: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       5     0  this   LExample;
    RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations:
      0: #22()
        lombok.Generated
```

and generates JaCoCo report in `module/build/reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html`
that doesn't show methods with these annotations:

[image]